# sqlite3_column_text returning Null

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I have a table and I want to print the content of a row here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE "quotes_type" ("type_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL , "content" TEXT)
```

I can see the type_id with debug and the value is correctly 1 but I can't return the context value with the help of sqlite3_column_text here is the code:

```
    NSString *qry = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"select * from quotes_type"];
    const char *count_stmt = [qry UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, count_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ERROR) {
        NSAssert1(0,@"Error when selecting rows  %s",sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));
    } else {
        int myid=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);

        NSLog(@"Context: %s", sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1));
        NSLog(@"myid is %d",myid);

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
```

the problem is this line:

```
   NSLog(@"Data: %s", sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1));
```

the result is Null

I realized that it doesn't update my sqlite file and it is reading from my previous one how can I force it to read from the new one?even I deleted all .sqlite files but still it is reading it from somewhere

Comment: Perhaps the table actually contains NULL in the second column of that row? Did you check the contents with the sqlite3 command line tool, or with some SQLite browser?

Comment: I found the problem it is reading still from the previous sqlite file even when I deleted whole sqlite files it still was reading it and showing the id so I ran the query and drop the database

Comment: @MartinR my query drop database didn't work it is still reading it is there any way for example clear it?

Comment: When you delete the sqlite file then you have to close and re-open the sqlite handle (contactDB).

Comment: well I have it in my program I also cleaned the build but this is reading from the bundle and as I understood I can not delete the bundle file I tried a sample code and it didn't work sigh